# How to write "Show" Typeclass for data

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, typeclass

I have a very simple `data` and I want to use `Show` Typeclass to give it a nice output.

```
data Fruit = Apple | Orange Int 

instance Show Fruit
         where
            show Apple    = "Hey Apple"
            show Orange a = "X number of Orange"
```

This gives the following error but I don't know how to fix it:

```
Equations for `show' have different numbers of arguments
```

Comment: Keep in mind that the `Show` typeclass is generally used to generate strings corresponding to the representation of what you're showing i.e. `read . show` is equivalent to `id`. If you're defining a function that pretty prints, it would be more idiomatic to call it something like `printFruit`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You just forgot some parens :)

```
instance Show Fruit where
  show Apple      = "Hey Apple"
  show (Orange a) = show a ++ " number of Orange"
```

Patterns like `Orange a` need parens to disambiguate from something like `Apple a` where we really have two arguments.

Comment: @MikaelS. Anytime, best of luck with the rest of Haskell :)