# How to convert Maybe a to a or -1 (for nothing)?

Tags: haskell, option-type

I'd line to convert Just a to a and Nothing to -1 where a is an Int.

My function is:

```
--Converts Just a to a && Nothing to -1
justToIntOnly :: (Integral a) => Maybe a -> a
justToIntOnly Just a = a
justToIntOnly Nothing = -1
```

The error i get is:
"Equations for `justToIntOnly' have different numbers of arguments"

I dont really understand whats going on,

Comment: add paréntesis `justToIntOnly (Just a)`. Also check function `maybe` from `Data.Maybe`

Comment: Oh thanks so simple

Comment: `justToIntOnly = Data.Maybe.fromMaybe (-1)`

Comment: I wonder why do you want to do such a conversion. Note that, in Haskell, representing an "invalid" integer result as `-1` is not idiomatic, and using `Nothing` would be the right way. Unless you need to interface with some software / server / library / format / whatever which mandates `-1`, you should keep your `Nothing`s as they are.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to write "Show" Typeclass for data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23413691/how-to-write-show-typeclass-for-data)

Comment: I need to do this chi because I want to use elemIndex function's result Maybe to actually access an index in a list.

Comment: That sounds quite weird. `elemIndex` requires an element `x` to search, and gives you `Just index` on success. If you access the list at `index` you get back the element `x` you searched for. Isn't that unnecessary? Further, we have plenty of functions to work with a `Maybe Int`, including `fmap` and all the applicative/monadic functions. If we have `position :: Maybe Int`, we can use `(list !!) <$> position` and get `Just element` (if `position == Just index`) or `Nothing` (otherwise). The nothing-ness gets propagated nicely, as it should. Using `case .. of` is also a lower level option.

Answer (score 6):

You just forgot the parenthesis, remember what you're doing is actually a pattern matching:

```
--Converts Just a to a && Nothing to -1
justToIntOnly :: (Integral a) => Maybe a -> a
justToIntOnly (Just a) = a
justToIntOnly Nothing  = -1
```

As someone pointed out in the comments, there are already functions to handle `Maybe` like you need, you can search Hoogle for `Maybe a -> a`:

The maybe function takes a default value, a function, and a Maybe value. If the Maybe value is Nothing, the function returns the default value. Otherwise, it applies the function to the value inside the Just and returns the result.

```
maybe :: b -> (a -> b) -> Maybe a -> b
```

You can use it like

```
justToIntOnly = maybe (-1) id
```

An even better function would be `fromMaybe :: a -> Maybe a -> a`, which takes a default value and and Maybe value. If the Maybe is Nothing, it returns the default values; otherwise, it returns the value contained in the Maybe.

```
justToIntOnly = fromMaybe (-1)
```